# How to make graphql work on ObservableHQ?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, observablehq

I am using observablehq for playing around with the `graphql` js library.

However, I fail at importing it and observable complains about this module.

Any hint? Do we need to modify the library to make it observable friendly?

Answer (score 1):

Observable has a [Module require debugger](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/module-require-debugger) for these situations; given a module name, it can often find a way to make it work. E.g., for GraphQL, it suggests using [Skypack](https://www.skypack.dev/), which works for me in a notebook:

`graphql = import('https://cdn.skypack.dev/graphql@15.4.0')`